# Regular Expression for Alpha numeric wildcard search

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I need a regular expression for a search box that takes only alphanumeric values, but allows wildcard search by taking "*" at the end.

Something like "123*", "abc*", or just "abc"

```
  $(".onlyAlphaNumericWildcard").keypress(function (e) {
     //Alphanumeric and also an optional "*" at the end
     var keyCode = e.which;
     var inp = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
     if (/[a-zA-Z0-9*]/.test(inp)) {
        return true;
     }
     return false;
   });
```

But the above one takes multiple * characters at any position. I want to limit this to only one and also IF POSSIBLE - at the end only.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\*?$`

Answer (score 0):

with this regex `/(^\w+\*$)|(^\w+$)/g` you can match `abc` or `abc*`

**OR** another way:  `^\w+\*?$`

`\*?$` : optional * in the end.

`^\w` : word 1 or more in the beginning

```js
const regex = /(^\w+\*$)|(^\w+$)/g;
const text = "abc"

console.log(text.match(regex))
```

Comment: `\w` matches not only `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: what else it does match?

Comment: At least `_` and other chars depending on regex engine

Comment: nice thank you i ll update my answer but another question what do you mean by regex engine the language used right ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, I believe I had this unpleasant experience with some legacy technology, but normally `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z_]`

Comment: Sorry, if I am doind it something wrong. But this doesnt work for me.                
       if (/(^\w+\*$)|(^\w+$)/g.test(inp)) {
           return true;
        }
        return false;   It is not accepting "*" at all